# Xamarin forms: Display Alert is not working in XF version 4.6 on UWP platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

For implementing expander on my project I have updated my XF version to 4.6.0.726. After that, the `displayalert` is not working on the xamarin UWP project. Working fine on android and ios platforms.

My Code:

```
await DisplayAlert("Alert","Hiiiii","Ok");
```

This is an issue with the XF new version, How can I solve this? I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=184p9H5wPNvGmOoX3OrqVMVp2vf38ZaKV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems an known issue after XF 4.5 pre 4 . Here is a [similar thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9606) .

Changing the UWP target version to **1903** will solve it.

In addition , we could use the plugin [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) as a workaround . I think it will be solved in next release version as soon as possible .

Comment: You could search the issue in github directly .

Answer (score 0):

I will post this additional answer for anyone else having this problem. I also had the problem with the display alert not working, it was working fine on my Android project but on my UWP testing it would just freeze up. I searched the internet for hours and hours, no posted answers I found would work for me. I tried changing the Windows target version from Fall Creators update to version 1809 and finally the issue went away! Here is how to do it in Visual Studio:

Right-click on your UWP project and select properties
[image: select UWPproperties]

The properties window will come up. Select the Assemblies tab. Select the target version.
[image]